# Performance issue getting data from Oracle using Python and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm using the `cx_Oracle` module to create an `sqlalchemy` engine and retrieve data from an Oracle database using Python and Pandas, but I have an issue with performance, and I'm getting database errors.

My code works OK (but slow) if I specify just a couple of columns, and after a long time I can get all the 3.5 million rows. Here's the code I'm using:

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
import config
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://config.user:config.password@config.host:1521/?service_name=config.service')

sql = "select ITEM_NO, COUNTRY_CODE, LANGUAGE_CODE from table_ben_l_t where (LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es' and COUNTRY_CODE = 'ES')"

df = pd.read_sql(sql, engine)
```

As soon as I add more columns, I can't run this anymore as I'm getting a database error after a long, long delay (I'm talking hours).

I know that using this method to retrieve the data and create Pandas is not the only one available, however it is definitely the most convenient... Is there a better/safer way to get this data from the Oracle DB? I was thinking about downloading the rows chunk by chunk, dumping them into a list of dict that could be passed to Pandas, but this doesn't seem very "elegant"... I'm sure there must be a better way to do this... :-)

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me! :-)

JF

**EDIT 1:**
In response to @OldProgrammer and @crocarneiro:

There are no indexes to the columns according to the result of the query `select * from all_ind_columns where table_name = 'TABLE_BEN_L_T';`

**EDIT 2:**
This is the error message that I received:

```
DatabaseError: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number 509 with name "_SYSSMU509_3146905099$" too small
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/4xp6)
```

Thanks a lot too **@Christopher Jones**! This looks very interesting!

Comment: are there indexes on the columns in your WHERE clause?

Comment: When you say, you are getting database error, can you please elaborate a bit more on that? Also, it would be easier to provide suggestions if you mention the use case of your code - what do you intend to do with 3.5M rows? and do you really need these many for further processing and so on

Comment: Hello @OldProgrammer, I'm really not that familiar with databases in general, I can only write simple queries similar to the one I used. Could you please tell me how I can find the information about the indexes?

Comment: Hi @jfpelletier, barging in: if you are using a oracle database and want to know if there are any indexes in your table you can perform this query: `select * from all_ind_columns where table_name = 'TABLE_BEN_L_T';`. The query will return the columns indexed and the indexes names. If you are using SQL Developer, or Toad, or other IDE usually a SHIFT + F4 or CTRL + click in the table name shows you this information.

Comment: You need to tune the number of batches that the data is fetched in.  Fundamentally this is handled by cx_Oracle underneath Pandas with `fetcharraysize` and the newer `prefetchrows` attributes.  Doc for tuning is here [Tuning Fetch Performance](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html#tuning-fetch-performance).  Also see https://oralytics.com/2018/11/14/reading-data-from-oracle-table-into-python-pandas-how-long-different-arraysize/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue by tuning the `fetcharraysize` and the `prefetchrows` attributes as suggested by Christopher Jones.

I dramatically improved the performance by setting the values of the attributes, and no more time-outs and error messages!

Thanks very much all who helped! :-)

JF

Comment: Hi jfpelletier. This fits more as a comment rather than an answer. If you want to contribute to SO, it would be great if you could expand on your answer and show the solution.